# How to scale multiple divs and stay inside of container?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scale, css-transforms

I'm building a grid UI, where users should be able to click on cells to scale them.

**Desired Behavior:**

- Cells should *not* scale out of the container and be cropped*.
- Cells *can* overlap other cells (when scaled).
- (Only *one* cell need be scaled at a time. This is not our prime concern).

***Left: Unwanted behavior** (parts of cell `O` are gone).
**Right: Desired behavior**
[image]

**My Approach:**

Obviously, I can `transform: scale() translate()` at the same time, to reach the desired result.
You can see this with **cell `N`** (`translateY(22px)`).

**Problems:**

This approach doesn't scale well to 9 cells (let alone 90, which is my actual use case).

The container *must* be `overflow: hidden`. Scrolling etc. are not an option.

**My Question(s):**

This feels like a pretty crude attempt at solving something that *someone must have solved* already programmatically.

**Is there a better way to build such a UI?** (I'm open to plugins or other approaches).

If not, what's a good way to script this in jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
$(".cell").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("zoom-in");
  });
});
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
  background: tomato;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-in {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}

#nord {
  background-color: white;
}
#nord.zoom-in {
  transform: scale(2) translateY(22px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> Click white and red cells to scale. Click again to revert.</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">NW</div>
  <div id="nord" class="cell">N</div>
  <div class="cell">NO</div>
  <div class="cell">W</div>
  <div class="cell">C</div>
  <div class="cell">O</div>
  <div class="cell">SW</div>
  <div class="cell">S</div>
  <div class="cell">SO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's @Akshay, it works. Unfortunately, it disables the second click (to revert `scale` completely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up a function that evaluates if the cell is near the border (any border) of the grid. If this is the case, injects a style on the cell setting a transform style property that will make it move in the opposite direction of the border when zoomed.

This is a quick and dirty approach, obviously there is room for improvement.

```js
$(function() {
$(".cell").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("zoom-in");
  });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setEvent, false);

function setEvent () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
    var grid = elements[0].parentElement;

    var gridWidth = grid.clientWidth;
    var gridHeight = grid.clientHeight;
    var maxGrid = {
        right: gridWidth,
        bottom: gridHeight
    }

    

    for (var n = 0; n < elements.length; n++) {
        evaluate (elements[n], maxGrid);
    }
}

function evaluate (element, maxGrid) {

    var transOrigin = "";

    var left = element.offsetLeft;
    if (left < element.clientWidth) {
        transOrigin += 'left ';
    }
    if (left + element.clientWidth > maxGrid.right - element.clientWidth) {
        transOrigin += 'right ';
    }


    var top = element.offsetTop;
    if (top < element.clientHeight) {
        transOrigin += 'top';
    }
    if (top + element.clientHeight > maxGrid.bottom - element.clientHeight) {
        transOrigin += 'bottom';
    }


    element.style.transformOrigin = transOrigin;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; /* important to have this */
}

.cell {
  background: tomato;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.zoom-in {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}

#nord {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div> Click white and red cells to scale. Click again to revert.</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">NW</div>
  <div id="nord" class="cell">N</div>
  <div class="cell">NO</div>
  <div class="cell">W</div>
  <div class="cell">C</div>
  <div class="cell">O</div>
  <div class="cell">SW</div>
  <div class="cell">S</div>
  <div class="cell">SO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @vals! Good idea to use the `.clientWidth`/ `.clientHeight` with the `.offset...`  property. The problem is cell `C`. It transforms with `+= 'bottom'`even if it is in the middle.

Comment: It's working ok now. I was using offsetTop to get the top coordinates relative to the grid, and this requires the grid to be positioned. Adding position: relative to it solves the issue

Comment: I was able to adapt your approach to my use case (with small additions), thank's again @vals.

Comment: @vals very sorry, I erroneously downvoted, and now can't change my vote. Could you add a trivial edit so I can upvote again?

Answer (score 1):

I created something similar as a proof of concept. I think it may help point you in the right direction. Check out the demo here: https://codepen.io/RTakes/pen/aWejOy

This is how I handled centering when also scaling.  It calculates the position to animate to, from it's current position.

```
function computeCenterPosition(element, sizeFactor = 0) {
  const screenCenter = {
    x: window.innerWidth / 2,
    y: window.innerHeight / 2
  };

  const elCenter = {
    x: (element.offsetWidth / 2) + element.offsetLeft,
    y: (element.offsetHeight / 2) + element.offsetTop
  };

  return {
    x: (elCenter.x - screenCenter.x) * -1,
    y: (elCenter.y - screenCenter.y) * -1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's @RickTakes! The problem with modal dialogs is that they constantly interrupt the user interaction... There must be a more intuitive way.